# User can download same application in many device using same apple id

Tags: iphone, app-store

User can download same application in many device using same apple id? is it written in any document? or is there any restriction on downloading same app ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing app in multiple devices in development phase than you have to add all devices UDID in your apple account.

No issue for same appID

Comment: I am asking for downloading app from App Store

Comment: Is there any written statement by Apple ?

Comment: no issue you can try by download in two different devices from same aapple ID

Comment: any written statement for this ?

Comment: why did you need statement if you can test it use some common sense

Comment: I know that I have also tested that in several devices but some client want in written thats why.